# Releasing highlighted state for UITableViewCell after returning to the screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

In UITableView, when tapping and holding a cell and (without releasing this cell) switching to another screen in tab bar and returning to the initial one, the cell remains highlighted (not selected) and if tapping on another cell, the first one gets selected.

Upon tapping and holding the first cell, `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` is called for the first cell. So far it is how it should be.

Upon tapping on another cell (after returning to the screen), `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didUnhighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` is called for the ***first*** cell. And then all methods for selection for the ***first*** cell.

Is there a way to remove this behaviour? And upon returning to the screen have no highlighted cells.

`cell.setHighlighted(false, animated: false)` doesn't work. Yes, it removes highlighting, but selection methods are again called for the ***first*** cell.

Comment: You can use delegate to inform previous screen to reload Table on back from oter screens.

Comment: Solved by reloading first cell, but it is very unappealing solution.

Comment: What is being used to switch screens (when you tap and hold?)... If a cell is in a highlighted state, I think it is natural for it to want to `didUnhighlightRowAt`, and that chain of events also leads to `tableView(_:willSelectRowAt:) -> 
tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:). This is deep in the behavior, the only thing I've found that breaks the selection processing is tap-hold-drag up/down... the cell unhighlights and the selection never takes place.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to implement `shouldHighlightRowAt` and return `false`?

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614988-tableview) for `tableView(_:shouldHighlightRowAt:)`:

> Asks the delegate if the specified row should be highlighted.

Comment: If you like the highlight change (want to only stop the delayed selection), then you'd want to put in the highlighting effects by hand....